# 'url' tag for tornado (python) with parameters, just like in Django Template Language

Tags: python, django, templates, tornado

Like in Django, we can use DTL(Django Template Language) {% url 'url_name' %} instead of hard coding URL names. Is anything of that sort is available while using Tornado (python)?

Comment: Do let me know where you are with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{ reverse_url('login') }}`. That is, a template expression rather than directive. The [syntax reference is here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html#syntax-reference) (it's brief).

For example,

To name the urls you need full `URLSpec` objects -- see [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.URLSpec)

In this particular example, you can easily use the helper `tornado.web.url` function:

```
from tornado.web import url

urls = [
    url(r"/", IndexHandler, name="home"),
]
```

And in template access it like so

```
<a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="{{reverse_url('home')}}">
```

**Update:**
To pass with parameters, follow the method below.

Use reverse_url to construct the base url, and then add query parameters afterwards. Example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25332169/tornado-reverse-url-encodes-special-characters-like-and)

```
{{ reverse_url("web-html", "list-builds") + "?" + urlencode(dict(bundle_identifier=app.bundle_identifier)) }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked, but also can you tell me what if I had to pass parameters along with the user. Like if home had a parameter say, home/username. How can we pass the value of the parameter along with it?

Comment: To pass parameters you need to do that in javascript, e.g. on button click. Reverser url simply `Returns url string for a given route name`

Comment: Sorry am still stuck a problem, I'm not getting redirected properly

Comment: No worries. If you have a new problem, ask that as a new question since this answer solves the current question. Give me a link to the new question here so i can look into it

Comment: okay so, when I added parameters like {{ reverse_url('home', username }}, assuming username was taken from tornado having value 'abcd' and am wanting to redirect to page: /home/abcd   But I'm being redirected to /home/abcd? and am getting a 404 error.

Comment: see my updated answer. So this should be something like `/home/username?abcd`